# How to update a tkinter button that reads from a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

For a quick intro to what i'm doing:

I'm using [customtkinter](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter) to create a GUI. My goal is to have a user input an application path and a name for a button. It then adds to a text file the ID (name) and PATH (app location).

The images below show what the user sees before any data is entered:
[image: Current Apps Tab before information is entered]
[image: Add Apps entry fields]
[image: Remove Apps before information is entered]

Lets say the user then posts some names and paths through the Add Apps function. The originally emtpy text file now looks like this:

```
ID=[name1]
PATH=path1
ID=[name2]
PATH=path2
ID=[name3]
PATH=path3
ID=[name4]
PATH=path4
```

The Current Apps and Remove Apps tabs then read the file and display the buttons such as:
[image]
I have the start app function working; when a button is clicked it reads the file and finds the corresponding ID using lambda and everything works how it should when reading the path and starting the app under the specific ID.

When a path and name is added to the text file, the corresponding buttons are immediately added to both the current apps and remove apps tabs.

Let's say for example I want to delete the button named "name1". I read the file and delete the contents:

```
ID=[name1]
PATH=path1
```

Once I delete the lines above it still shows the "name1" button until i restart the program. How am I able to delete the button after deleting the corresponding file contents without closing the program?

In other words: such like how I add a name and path to the text file it adds a button for it, how can I do it vise versa so when I delete the specific lines that a button reads from the text file it deletes the specific button as well?

Here is my add_app function:

```
def add_app(self):

        # get path and button name from entries
        path_location = app_path.get()                            
        path_name = app_name.get()                                 

        # delete entry fields  
        self.entry_add_apps_name.delete(0, "end")                 
        self.entry_add_apps_path.delete(0, "end")                   
        
        # open data file
        with open('ez_start_path_file.txt') as infile:
            k = 0
            # count lines in file
            for line in infile:
                k += 1
            # if file lines are 64 or higher (if there are 24 buttons)
            # don't write to file and notify user of maximum limit
            if k >= 64:
                self.label_no_more_apps_notice = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.tabview.tab("Add Apps"), text="You have reached the maximum limit.")
                self.label_no_more_apps_notice.grid(row=8, column=0)
                self.after(2500, lambda: self.label_no_more_apps_notice.destroy())  
            # if there is open space (23 or less buttons)
            if k < 64:
                # chech if fields are empty and if not then open file
                if path_location == '' or path_name == '':
                    print('empty fields') 
                # once file is open enter the ID and path location and notify user of successful update
                else:
                    f = open("ez_start_path_file.txt", "a")                     
                    f.write('ID=['+path_name+']\nPATH='+path_location+'\n')     
                    f.close()                                                   
                    self.label_confirm_add = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.tabview.tab("Add Apps"), text="Sucessfully Added!")
                    self.label_confirm_add.grid(row=8, column=0)
                    self.after(2500, lambda: self.label_confirm_add.destroy()) 

                # open file         
                with open('ez_start_path_file.txt') as infile:
                    # count lines in file
                    i = 0
                    for line in infile:
                        i += 1
                        # search for text inside brackets []
                        m = re.search(r'.*?\[(.*)].*', line)
                        if m:
                            # for buttons 1-8, print button in middle column
                            if i <= 15:
                                self.button_add_apps = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.tabview.tab("Current Apps"), text=m.group(1), command= lambda rw = i: self.start_app(rw))
                                self.button_add_apps.grid(row=i, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)

                                self.label_remove_apps = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.tabview.tab("Remove Apps"), text=m.group(1), command= lambda rw = i: self.remove_app(rw))
                                self.label_remove_apps.grid(row=i, column=0, padx=15, pady=15)

                                # configure grid for singular column
                                self.tabview.tab("Current Apps").grid_columnconfigure((0), weight=1)
                                self.tabview.tab("Remove Apps").grid_columnconfigure((0), weight=1)  
                            # for buttons 9-16, print the two columns 
                            if i > 16:
                                self.button_add_apps = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.tabview.tab("Current Apps"), text=m.group(1), command= lambda rw = i: self.start_app(rw))
                                self.button_add_apps.grid(row=i - 16, column=1, padx=15, pady=15)

                                self.label_remove_apps = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.tabview.tab("Remove Apps"), text=m.group(1), command= lambda rw = i: self.remove_app(rw))
                                self.label_remove_apps.grid(row=i - 16, column=1, padx=15, pady=15)

                                # configure grid for 2 columns
                                self.tabview.tab("Current Apps").grid_columnconfigure((0), weight=1)
                                self.tabview.tab("Remove Apps").grid_columnconfigure((0, 1), weight=1) 
                            # for buttons 17-24, print 3 columns 
                            if i > 32:
                                self.button_add_apps = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.tabview.tab("Current Apps"), text=m.group(1), command= lambda rw = i: self.add_app(rw))
                                self.button_add_apps.grid(row=i - 32, column=2, padx=15, pady=15)

                                self.label_remove_apps = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.tabview.tab("Remove Apps"), text=m.group(1), command= lambda rw = i: self.remove_app(rw))
                                self.label_remove_apps.grid(row=i - 32, column=2, padx=15, pady=15)

                                # configure 3 columns
                                self.tabview.tab("Current Apps").grid_columnconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)
                                self.tabview.tab("Remove Apps").grid_columnconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)
```

And here is my remove app function

```
def remove_app(self, rw):
        with open('ez_start_path_file.txt', 'r') as fr:
            # read lines and assign to 'lines'
            lines = fr.readlines()
            # assign pointer
            ptr = 1
            # open file
            with open('ez_start_path_file.txt', 'w') as fw: 
                # cycle through lines
                for line in lines:
                    # detect button path and ID
                    if ptr != rw and ptr != rw+1:
                        # delete lines
                        fw.write(line)
                    ptr += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tkinter after() function to update you widget after some ms Intervall:

```
widget.after(delay, callback=None)
```

Here you can find some [Examples](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-after/)